# Connecting MySQL database remotely on a hosting provider secure?

Tags: mysql, java

My JavaFX Desktop Application is currently connected to a hosted MySQL database remotely on bluehost. I query "SELECT", "UPDATE", "DELETE" on my JavaFX Application and successfully done.

My question is. Is this approach secure?

I am using JDBC driver to connect through it.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql_ip_on_bluehost_here:3306/my_db", dbUser, dbPass);
```

Comment: You should probably also look into using stored procedures instead of using "raw" sql in the program code.

Comment: wow thats a pretty awesome idea. any good link for a tutorial?

Comment: This is pretty good as it shows both commandline and workbench http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it isn't secure. From a sysadmin point of view: both your credentials as well as all data will be transmitted unencrypted.

Although MySQL does support transport layer security (SSL/TLS) it isn't enabled by default and after [setting up server support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-ssl-connections.html) you'll need to [explicitly instruct the client to use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) it as well.

Typically that would result in something along the lines of:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql_ip_on_bluehost_here:3306/my_db?useSSL=true", dbUser, dbPass)
```

An alternative would be something like IPSec that provides security on the IP layer rather than the application layer.

From a DBA point of view @M_dk made a good point that allowing direct SQL UPDATE and DELETE statements are not desirable and stored procedures are much better from a security perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not specified useSSL anywhere, then on it's own, no.  For now login details will be sent in the clear, as would all other transactions.  Please see [Connecting Securely Using SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) from the MySQL website.

Comment: Using SSL does not make it 100% secure - what is.